# Terraform for loop inside for_each argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, terraform, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

Can someone please explain what a for loop inside a for_each argument does in Terraform? I am trying to create an AWS SSL certificate. I've seen other code like the below but I don't understand it:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "nonprod_cert" {
    domain_name       = var.phz_domain_name
    validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "nonprod_cert_record" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.nonprod_cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
        name   = dvo.resource_record_name
        record = dvo.resource_record_value
        type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }
  zone_id = var.phz_id
  name    = each.value.name
  type    = each.value.type
  records = [each.value.record]
  ttl     = 60
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "nonprod_cert_validated" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.nonprod_cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.nonprod_cert_record : record.fqdn]
  depends_on = [
    aws_acm_certificate.nonprod_cert,
    aws_route53_record.nonprod_cert_record
  ]
}
```

The specific line that I don't understand is the one in the route53 record. I get that a for_each argument can be used to create multiple resources from a single block, but I can't find anywhere that explains what this for loop is doing inside of it. If someone could explain that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

The inner for "loop" creates the data that the `for_each` then iterates over. Specifically the `each.key` will be the `dvo.domain_name` and the `each.value` will be the

```
{
    name   = dvo.resource_record_name
    record = dvo.resource_record_value
    type   = dvo.resource_record_type
}
```

You could simply move that into a `locals` block beforehand and not have it in a single line:

```
locals { 
    records = {
        for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.nonprod_cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
            name   = dvo.resource_record_name
            record = dvo.resource_record_value
            type   = dvo.resource_record_type
        }
    }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "nonprod_cert_record" {
    for_each = local.records
    zone_id = var.phz_id
    name    = each.value.name
    type    = each.value.type
    records = [each.value.record]
    ttl     = 60
}
```

That will have the exact same effect.

Comment: thank you @luk2302. I was watching https://youtu.be/rnk3lfLYgrE?t=455 trying to understand further. He uses the for loop to assign, 'k' and 'v' to the key, values in a map. So is this for loop in the question I asked, basically saying I want to create custom maps with the parameters I pass in, i.e. name(key) =  dvo.resource_record_name(value)

Answer (score 3):

First they are using a [for](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) expression to convert one type of object into another type. In this case they are converting the list of `domain_validation_options` into a list of objects that can be used for creating `aws_route53_record` resources.

Next they are using [for_each](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/for-each) to create a new `aws_route53_record` resource for each element of the list that was generated by the `for` expression.

The key things to be aware of here are:

- `for` is used to convert a list of objects into a list of different objects.
- `for_each` is used to create multiple resources from a list, set, or map of values.

I highly recommend spending the time to go through the [Terraform learning site](https://learn.hashicorp.com/collections/terraform/configuration-language), or at least the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/index.html) to learn the basic keywords and overall syntax.

Comment: thank you @markB, I was watching youtu.be/rnk3lfLYgrE?t=455 trying to understand further. He uses the for loop to assign, 'k' and 'v' to the key, values in a map. So is this for loop in the question I asked, basically saying I want to create custom maps with the parameters I pass in, i.e. name(key) = dvo.resource_record_name(value)